# Advantages of Paillier vs Goldwasser-Micali

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, paillier

It is easy to see that both Paillier and Goldwasser-Micali are homomorphic addition schemes and are secure, but what would be the advantages of choosing one over the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're both additively homomorphic, but over different groups.

With Goldwasser-Micali, you can, given $E(x)$ and $E(y)$, compute $E(x \oplus y)$ (where $\oplus$ is exclusive or)

With Pallier, you can, given $E(x)$ and $E(y)$, compute $E(x + y \bmod n)$, where $n$ is a large integer; this implies that, given $E(x)$ and $k$, you can compute $E(kx \bmod n)$

Which is appropriate depends on what operation you need to perform on the encrypted data.

In my experience, we almost always want the operations that Pallier provides.

Comment: so basically goldwasser micali can only do homomorphic xor but not homomorphic addition?

Comment: @DanielK: that is correct (unless you mean addition in $GF(2)$, which is xor…)